# I need to accept an answer, but whose?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I had a problem that I [asked about on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37805758/bootstrap-affix-reset-not-works/37895187?noredirect=1#comment63378095_37895187). I put a bounty on it, because I didn't get an answer at first.

Two people then added answers. Dekel answered first, but I was on holiday so did not check their answer. Tasos K.'s answer was more detailed, with a jsfiddle demo, and I think that they had done much more work on that answer.

Anyway, both of the answers helped me. How should I choose here? My heart says Dekel; their answer was the first, even if the other answer was more upvoted.

Comment: 1. You don't **need** to accept anything - it isn't and was never a requirement. 2. Whatever helped you most is what you should accept if you choose to do so.

Comment: @Oded 1: Yes, I know, but because I put it on bounty, and I get the correct answer(s), I think, I should accept.